# Letter Order is Reversed (ereht olleH)

Tags: html, css, forms, user-interface, drupal-7

Every once in a while, a user of my website encounters the strange behaviour of the letters reversing order. While a refresh would solve the problem in this use case, it's annoying.

```html
Username: <br>
<input type="text" value="&#8238;John Doe">
```

I have tried researching possible CSS or HTML reasons to no avail.

Sebastian Simon mentioned that ['RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm) might be the culprit, but I am flabbergasted as to how would this character get into an input.

Should I just guess that it's a buggy Chrome extension?

Comment: [`dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir), [U+202E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm) or [U+200F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark), for example. Is this question programming related?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSimon. U+202E might be the [culprit](https://jsfiddle.net/du89cLkh/2/).